# How do I find the average gas price of a given block?

Tags: web3js, gas-price, ethers.js

How do I find the average gas price of a given block? This doesn't appear to be an easily accessible thing in ethers.js or Web3.js, but hopefully I'm just missing something.

Comment: Usually the need is to be able to compute the gas price required to send a TX, and it's not calculated on only one block as it can vary a lot. It's a median (not average), of the gas price of some of the last blocks. For instance you have this in Besu client RPC API https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/Reference/API-Methods/#eth_gasprice what's your need for an average of a specific block?